# SQL Server - Loop every column name and compare its name and execute a script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this code to show the list of columns in my table Customer:

```
select Column_name 
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name = 'Customer'
```

Now I want to loop every single column and compare it and execute a script.
Here is my [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBOWd.png). Thank you all. New SQL dev here :)

Comment: Can you share details about this script?

Comment: Hi Tim! Its a dynamic sql that uses the name of the column and execute a query. So basically I need the column names 1 by 1. It is kind of a logs of a table. I didn't use a trigger to do the logs because of some matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Column_Name VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer'

OPEN column_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor
    INTO @Column_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        IF @Column_Name IN ('Name', 'Surname')
        OR LEN(@Column_Name) > 1
        BEGIN

                PRINT @Column_Name

                -- Perform some other operation

        END


        FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor
            INTO @Column_Name

END

CLOSE column_cursor
DEALLOCATE column_cursor
```